# skip splits in character string

Tags: r

I need to generate a list of sequences from a database, in which a split pattern is skipped up to n-times. As I only know R, I would appreciate an R solution.

Example:
character string:

"GRGKA"

I could use a simple
`strsplit()`
function but this would result in a "perfect" split pattern.

What I am looking for is all combinations that are generated when n number of splits are skipped.

I specifically want to split the string after K or R (so that K and R are still included in the reported split sequence)

so a normal split would yield:
"GR" "GK" "A"

however with one "skipped" split it would look like this:
"GRGK" "GKA"

and with two skipped splits:
"GRGKA"

I was not able to find something online. Sorry if I missed something or did not provide enough info.

Here is the code that I started out with and which provides a normal split without skipping K or R

```
`"GRGKA" %>% strsplit(., "(?<=K|R)", perl = TRUE)`

[[1]]
[1] "GR" "GK" "A"
```